# How do i get list of wifi AP and connect to one AP from Windows store app

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-store-apps, wifi, wifi-direct

I want to scan and list the available WIFI access points and allow user to connect to one from a custom interface on a Windows Store app.

I am aware of the WiFi native API, but this is not accessible in Windows store App.

Can I use WifiDirect API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Windows 8.1:**

You best work with WiFi Direct on Windows 8.1. Your devices have to support Wifi Direct. 
"You can use Wi-Fi Direct to both enumerate a list of Wi-Fi Direct devices within wireless range, and then set up a socket connection between apps using Wi-Fi Direct devices."
See full Sample here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WiFiDirectDevice-sample-59a6e5e0#content

**For Windows 10:** 
You can use Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter to do this in a Windows Store App.
Make sure you set the capability in the app manifest:

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl" />
```

Here's a codesample that basically does the trick and simply connects to a network with the ssid "MyNetworkSSID".

```
using Windows.Devices.WiFi;


    var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
    var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
    if (result.Count >= 1)
    {
// take first adapter
    nwAdapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
// scan for networks
    await nwAdapter.ScanAsync();
// find network with the correct SSID
var nw = nwAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Where(y => y.Ssid.ToLower() == "MyNetworkSSID").FirstOrDefault();
// connect 
    await nwAdapter.ConnectAsync(nw, WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic);
   }
```

Comment: I am afraid Windows.Devices.WiFi is only supported on windows 10. Is there a way i can use this API on windows 8.1?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you're talking about W8.1. I edited my answer. On 8.1 you can't use the Windows.Devices.WiFi namespace. You have to go with Wifi direct.

Comment: Daniel - nwAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Where[...] is giving me back a null, and trying to inspect the AvailableNetworks doesn't seem to give me anything useful (I can't see networks). Do you have a working example solution I could take a look at? Thanks